# Elliptic Curve with Digital Signature Algorithm (ECDSA) implementation on BouncyCastle

Tags: java, cryptography, bouncycastle

I am trying to implement ECDSA (Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm) but I couldn't find any examples in Java which use Bouncy Castle. I created the keys, but I really don't know what kind of functions I should use to create a signature and verify it.

```
public static KeyPair GenerateKeys()
    throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
{
    ECParameterSpec ecSpec = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec("B-571");
    KeyPairGenerator g = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECDSA", "BC");
    g.initialize(ecSpec, new SecureRandom());
    return g.generateKeyPair();
}
```

Comment: it didn't help, but I did create the same question also at crypto.stackexchange.com

Comment: A few years ago, code samples of correct usage of encryption libraries was on topic.  I'm not so sure if that's the case now.  ... though it would be nice to have a place rich with accurate, vetted, security-related code.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

owlstead is correct.  And to elaborate a bit more, you can do this:

```
KeyPair pair = GenerateKeys();
Signature ecdsaSign = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withECDSA", "BC");
ecdsaSign.initSign(pair.getPrivate());
ecdsaSign.update(plaintext.getBytes("UTF-8"));
byte[] signature = ecdsaSign.sign();
```

And to verify:

```
Signature ecdsaVerify = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withECDSA", "BC");
ecdsaVerify.initVerify(pair.getPublic());
ecdsaVerify.update(plaintext.getBytes("UTF-8"));
boolean result = ecdsaVerify.verify(signature);
```

Comment: "the Java Security API Provider name is now SC rather than BC"
https://rtyley.github.io/spongycastle/

Comment: "BC" Is BouncyCastle "SC" is SpongyCastle which are two different providers. The question was about BouncyCastle which means the "BC" is correct, but "SC" is not

Comment: the API of BC seems to have changed enormously since this answer was posted. 1.60 does not work with this example code anymore :(

Comment: how can I get "pair" instance to verify? This can't be GenerateKeys(); as then it will different public key than the one of signing. I'm confused here.

Answer (score 7):

BouncyCastle is a *provider*: a set of classes which provides some cryptographic functionalities that applications are supposed to use through the generic API that Java comes with. See the [Java Cryptography Architecture](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#Signature), especially the section on signatures, to see how to generate or verify a signature. Basically, you get a `java.security.Signature` instance (with the static `getInstance()` method), then you initialize it with either a private key (`initSign()`, to generate a signature) or a public key (`initVerify()`, to verify a signature). You then input the message data with one or several `update()` calls, and finally you call `sign()` or `verify()`, to generate or verify a signature.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be using Bouncy Castle mainly as provider. In that case you could simply use `Signature.getInstance("SHA256withECDSA", "BC")`.